# Various Linux booting messages

Tags: fedora, boot, grub2

I just installed Fedora 39. When it boots it shows a huge message "Welcome to Grub!". (It does boot successfully, though.) A few months ago I had Fedora 37 and that message didn't exist.

I have also used Ubuntu extensively and it seemed to show different messages while booting as well, such as a list of loaded utilities etc...

Why there are different booting messages between Linux distros, between the same distro and between different versions the same distro?

Comment: Why not? Different boot seequences are written by different people, and there is no standard for transient boot up messages.

Comment: @waltinator Mainly the question is focused around why there is a difference between the booting messages of the same distribution installed on the same computer or between different versions of the same distribution installed again on the same computer.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple elements in the boot process, each of them quite customizable:

- GRUB, its themes, backgrounds and custom menu texts (in Debian an related distributions, you'll see a number of packages named `grub-theme-*`)
- a boot splash screen, these days often implemented with the `plymouth` package, with its own themes (see `sudo plymouth-set-default-theme -l` for a list of available boot themes)

Each distribution generally tries to make themselves distinctive, so they apply their own customizations to these. And they can, at their option, vary their customizations on each major release. Often these distribution-specific graphics are coordinated to make the transitions from GRUB to the boot splash and/or from the boot splash to the login screen as seamless as possible.

Sometimes the implementation quality of these boot themes may vary between distributions. I've seen some distributions that didn't copy any custom fonts or backgrounds to `/boot` if it exists as a separate filesystem, but attempted to read it directly from the root filesystem. If you chose to install with a root filesystem type or disk encryption type that was not directly supported by GRUB, it would cause these customizations to fail and GRUB to revert back to a more utilitarian, text-based look.

In other times, the choice of GPU driver may affect the type of boot display. In particular, installing the proprietary NVidia driver may have (/used to have?) the side effect of disabling the graphical boot splash, because the `plymouth` package does (/did?) not support the kind of advanced graphics framebuffer layouts the proprietary driver tends to use (optimized for GPU hardware acceleration rather than for easy boot display programming).

But in the end, these graphic elements and customizations are *optional*. If you make a minimal installation, some or all of them might be excluded, and the system would fall back to a display of default startup output: usually text-based GRUB menu, and a list of services started, with their start-up status in red/yellow/green as appropriate.

Usually the graphical boot splashes will allow you the option to see the service start-up confirmations by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>. But if you care more about easy troubleshooting than pretty graphics, you can make the start-up messages the default start-up view, with e.g. `sudo plymouth-set-default-theme details` or `sudo plymouth-set-default-theme text`. By either deleting the default kernel boot parameter  `quiet` or adding the parameter `verbose` (depending on distribution), you can also get the kernel hardware probe messages for even more verbose boot diagnostics, if necessary.

There's one special boot splash type that might be worth mentioning. If the firmware displays a system/motherboard vendor's logo at boot, it can also make that logo available to the operating system, using an ACPI table known as `BGRT` (Boot Graphic Resource Table, I think). The boot splash can then incorporate it into the boot splash screen, or create a smooth transition between it and the OS login screen, if desired. If your system supports it, you should be able to see the `/sys/firmware/acpi/bgrt/` directory, and so a selection of `sudo plymouth-set-default-theme bgrt` might be available.

Answer (score 3):

You may find this interesting: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/HiddenGrubMenu — that's the proposal where Fedora decided to hide the Grub menu by default. As that proposal explains:

> Fedora already has a lot of work done to not show too technical boot messages to end users during bootup, e.g. we pass quiet to the kernel and we've plymouth to show a bootsplash instead of a bunch of "Starting service-foo: OK" messages.

"plymouth" is the software that shows the distro logo during boot (instead of those service messages). You can actually see those if you want, though, by hitting "esc" at that part of the boot process.

All of this wasn't without controversy -- some people really like to see the technical messages, for diagnostic reasons and I think sometimes just because it seems cool in a geeky way. (I remember being drawn by those cryptic messages to learn more, the first time I saw a Linux system boot in 1993 or so....) So, you'll see different distributions make different choices. (In fact, if you install Fedora Linux Server Edition, or Fedora CoreOS, you'll see different behavior even within the Fedora family.)

Hans de Goede (who championed that proposal) is also responsible for other related changes, like https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/FlickerFreeBoot — on *any* distro, if the PC shows the manufacturer's logo and then smoothly shows a distro logo below that as the boot process continues... that's because of the work Hans did.

Anyway: why are you seeing the GRUB menu on Fedora Linux 39 when you weren't before? I can think of three possible reasons — two from the Change proposal, and one as a kind of catch-all:

1. You're now dual-booting with Windows or some other OS (that doesn't seem likely)
2. Something is preventing the system from shutting down cleanly (possibly a bug in some service, or in the kernel, or even in your system's firmware)
3. There's some other bug in configuration or upgrade. It happens!

Comment: I only see the "Welcome to GRUB!" message. I don't get the menu to choose where to boot to. Does this have to do with a bug?

Comment: @Adam If you hit `shift` while that message is displayed, do you see a menu?

Comment: I will try it and get back to you!